# CCNode+SFGestureRecognizer's working with ccTouch*?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using **CCNode+SFGestureRecognizer** https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/CCNode-SFGestureRecognizers for some pan gestures on some cocos2d nodes, but I also have other nodes that just use the normal **ccTouchBegan/Moved/Ended** and use the **CCTouchOneByOneDelegate**.

But I'm running into conflicts. With the ccTouch's overlapping I just set `swallowsTouches:NO`. Because basically what I'm doing is determining which touch to use in `ccTouchesMoved` based on the direction of the touch (is it mostly horizontal or mostly vertical) and if the direction matches a **particular nodes allowed direction**, that node **claims the touch** by canceling all of the other targeted handlers.

But when some nodes use the gesture recognizer, there doesn't seem to be an easy way for me to tell the touch to cancel when the direction is not in the allowed direction of that node. The `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` get's called before I can determine if the other touches should claim the touch. And I just don't know a proper way to cancel a gesture's touch.

**Any ideas for a good, clean way to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` in the CCNode+SFGestureRecognizers.m didn't have the correct translation/velocity information, however putting my own in the delegate did. The `shouldReceiveTouch` method in the delegate also did NOT have this information.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = (UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer;

        CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:pan.view];
        CGPoint velocity = [pan velocityInView:pan.view];

        CGPoint dragVector = /* detect direction of the translation/velocity */

        // if it was a horizontal drag return YES, otherwise NO
        if (dragVector.x != 0 && dragVector.y == 0) {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: SFGestureRecognizer just passes all the information to your delegate, so 'it didn't have correct...' is bad description.